# Image Search API v7 - How to limit number of result & image type

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

I had read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-images-api-v7-reference#filter , but hardly can find info regarding my question.

1. Is it possible to limit the search result to N items only?
2. How can I limit to search, to only PNG and BMP images?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set **count=N** for limiting search to N items. Also, use **imagetype:png** for example for the png images. The following yields 10 png images:

```
GET https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?q="birds imagetype:png"&count=10
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can specific both png images AND bmp images, in single GET request?

Comment: Just add formats to the list **imagetype:png,jpg** for example.

Comment: Hem, it is strange if I use jpg as imageType, there's no result : `https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?count=3&q=BILL+GATE+imagetype%3Ajpg;` . Png is OK - `https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?count=3&q=BILL+GATE+imagetype%3Apng`

Comment: It works for "jpeg" rather than for jpg - legacy reasons I think.